# Disable all keyboard shortcuts except for Alt+Tab in program

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, blender

I'm trying to use the 3D software Blender in Ubuntu and the software is very keyboard shortcut heavy. The issue is, a lot of the keyboard shortcuts overlap with Ubuntu's system shortcuts. For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> is a shortcut in Blender. However, Ubuntu overrides and displays a menu which allows me to minimize/close/maximize/etc the window. Is there any way to disable all the keyboard shortcuts except for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> when I'm using blender? I like the shortcuts in all my other programs, but since Blender has too many intersecting shortcuts, I just want to turn off the system shortcuts when I'm in Blender. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens quite often with default settings. A lots of applications rely on <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts but don't work because unity or compiz is already using them.

I don't know of a way to disable the shortcuts temporarily, but even if there is the best solution i've found is to avoid conflicts altogether. The first thing i do on a new setup is go through the desktop keyboard shortcut settings and have them use <kbd>Super</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

It makes things very clear:

- <kbd>Super</kbd> is for window manager actions
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> is always available for apps (except for <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Arrows</kbd> which i like to keep).

The "windows" keys act as <kbd>Super</kbd> by default, but you could have the "menu" key do it:
(i like to have it on the right side and there's no right "window" key on my keyboard)

**System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Layouts -> Options -> Alt/Win Key Behavior**
and choose **"Alt is mapped to Right Win, Super to Menu"**.

[image]

Now go through keyboard shortcut settings and change <kbd>Alt</kbd> bindings to <kbd>Super</kbd> ones.

Change compiz shortcuts as well with [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompositeManager#Install_CompizConfig_Settings_Manager) (install it first).
You can easily find all <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts with:
**Advanced Search -> Search in ... Settings value** and type "Alt"

That's it, you will never be annoyed by conflicting shortcuts again.