# Ubuntu system shortcut remains after disabling

Tags: shortcuts

I want to disable some Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS) system shortcuts

I tried System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts and then select the undesired shortcut to disabled it.

After reboot, the shortcut still works

I tried dconf Editor : org > gnome > desktop > vm > keybindings then select the undesired shortcut and set the value to ['disabled']

Doesn't work either : I can still use the shortcuts

The concerned shortcuts are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (toggle shading) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (lock screen).

Am I missing something here or can I use another way to disable these shortcuts ?

Comment: Please edit your question and say which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked is based on this response :  [Disable all keyboard shortcuts except for Alt+Tab in program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552035/disable-all-keyboard-shortcuts-except-for-alttab-in-program?rq=1)

- Install Compiz
- Go to Advanced Search > Search in ... (check "Setting Value")
- Type <Control><Alt> in the filter field
- Remove all occurrences of undesired shortcut by editing the fields (make it empty)